# python sqlalchemy + postgresql program freezes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've ran into a strange situation. I'm writing some test cases for my program. The program is written to work on sqllite or postgresqul depending on preferences. Now I'm writing my test code using unittest. Very basically what I'm doing:

```
def setUp(self):
    """
        Reset the database before each test.
    """
    if os.path.exists(root_storage):
        shutil.rmtree(root_storage)
    reset_database()
    initialize_startup()
    self.project_service = ProjectService()
    self.structure_helper = FilesHelper()
    user = model.User("test_user", "test_pass", "test_mail@tvb.org",
                       True, "user")
    self.test_user = dao.store_entity(user)
```

In the setUp I remove any folders that exist(created by some tests) then I reset my database (drop tables cascade basically) then I initialize the database again and create some services that will be used for testing.

```
def tearDown(self):
    """
        Remove project folders and clean up database.
    """
    created_projects = dao.get_projects_for_user(self.test_user.id)
    for project in created_projects:
        self.structure_helper.remove_project_structure(project.name)
    reset_database()
```

Tear down does the same thing except creating the services, because this test module is part of the same suite with other modules and I don't want things to be left behind by some tests.

Now all my tests run fine with sqllite. With postgresql I'm running into a very weird situation: at some point in the execution, which actually differs from run to run by a small margin (ex one or two extra calls) the program just halts. I mean no error is generated, no exception thrown, the program just stops.

Now only thing I can think of is that somehow I forget a connection opened somewhere and after I while it timesout and something happens. But I have A LOT of connections so before I start going trough all that code, I would appreciate some suggestions/ opinions.

What could cause this kind of behaviour? Where to start looking?

Regards,
Bogdan

Answer (score 38, accepted):

PostgreSQL based applications freeze because PG locks tables fairly aggressively, in particular it will not allow a DROP command to continue if any connections are open in a pending transaction, which have accessed that table in any way (SELECT included).

If you're on a unix system, the command "ps -ef | grep 'post'" will show you all the Postgresql processes and you'll see the status of current commands, including your hung "DROP TABLE" or whatever it is that's freezing.   You can also see it if you select from the pg_stat_activity view.

So the key is to ensure that no pending transactions remain - this means at a DBAPI level that any result cursors are closed, and any connection that is currently open has `rollback()` called on it, or is otherwise explicitly closed.  In SQLAlchemy, this means any result sets (i.e. `ResultProxy`) with pending rows are fully exhausted and any `Connection` objects have been `close()`d, which returns them to the pool and calls `rollback()` on the underlying DBAPI connection.   you'd want to make sure there is some kind of unconditional teardown code which makes sure this happens before any DROP TABLE type of command is emitted.

As far as "I have A LOT of connections", you should get that under control.  When the SQLA test suite runs through its 3000 something tests, we make sure we're absolutely in control of connections and typically only one connection is opened at a time (still, running on Pypy has some behaviors that *still* cause hangs with PG..its tough).   There's a pool class called `AssertionPool` you can use for this which ensures only one connection is ever checked out at a time else an informative error is raised (shows where it was checked out).

Comment: Would be good to mention this somewhere in the documentation. Encountered exactly the same problem after switching from sqlite to Postgre.

Comment: here you go, been there for years: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/FAQ#MyprogramishangingwhenIsaytable.dropmetadata.drop_all

Comment: "...which have accessed that table in any way (SELECT included)." Well, this saved my mental health! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Had the same problem with MySQL. All I had to do was `db.session.close_all()` and everything worked fine.

Comment: Here you go, that wiki, which zzzeek linked to, is only linking another website. Guess what, that website shows ... nothing, except a pre-release note. Not so great. Even when using `close_all()` after every test run, sometimes your can get the freezes.

Comment: I had this issue when running some tests with pytest, the fix for me was adding a missing `commit()` call in one of my session level fixtures. One of the more difficult issues I've had to debug. Thanks to @zzzeek for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 16):

One solution I found to this problem was to call `db.session.close()` before any attempt to call `db.drop_all()`. This will close the connection before dropping the tables, preventing Postgres from locking the tables.

See a much more in-depth discussion of the problem [here](https://kronosapiens.github.io/blog/2014/07/29/setting-up-unit-tests-with-flask/).

Comment: This answer provided my solution, and zzzeek answer explained the why. Thanks to both.

Comment: Still had freezes, although `close_all()` was used in teardown of a fixture in pytest, which was the only source of a session for all tests. So there is some other part to the freezes, which is not solved by this.